# Background video not showing up on GitHub Pages

Tags: html, css, github, html5-video, github-pages

I uploaded a site with Github Pages and noticed that the background video would not load on any of my other devices. The site loads fine on my main computer where I have the everything from the repository stored, but I don't know how to fix this issue so everything loads properly on my other devices.

Below is the HTML and CSS I wrote to display the video

```
<div class="background-container">
    <video autoplay loop muted playsinline>
      <source src="Images/video.mov" type="video/mov">
    </video>
</div>
```

```
.background-container {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: var(--primary-color) no-repeat center center/cover; 
}
```

So far I have tried placing 'background-image:url('file-location');' in the CSS above, and using mp4 instead of mov along with a few other things I've read on similar post but nothing seems to work.

Help would be greatly appreciated I'm really a complete beginner to all of this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an .mp4 version of the video instead of the .mov?

.mov is a Quicktime container for mp4, but in Chrome it often downloads rather than plays.

A list of device/browsers that worked vs. those that failed would help, but I'm pretty sure this will fix the issue.